# Control the LED blinking via on / off in a c program

Tags: c, controls, freebsd, led

I'm looking for suggestion and a bit of guidance if any of you had a similar problem.
I have 2 LED (green, red, dedicated pins) that I can control. The available commands are On / Off / Toggle.

I have written a small program in C to control the LEDs, and I can run it simply in terminal FreeBSD:

- led 1 : OFF green LED
- led 2 : ON green LED
- led 3 : blink green LED
- led 4 : OFF red LED
- led 5 : ON red LED
- led 6 : blink red LED

Now when it comes to blinking it is a bit more complicated, because it stays in the loop. I can use a timer, but that's not very useful to me ('cause I don't know for how long I will need it blinking).

```
while (1) {
  gpio_pin_high(handle, pin);
  sleep(1);
  gpio_pin_low(handle, pin);
  sleep(1);
}
```

My goal is to use LED blinking when a process starts - let's say it waiting to connect to WiFi. And when connected, use LED on.

I guess I can use fork() only for the blinking function, and when I want to turn LED on after having it blinking, I should check for the child process, stop and clean it up, and then call led_on function.

Thank you in advance for any ideas

Comment: You tagged both Arduino and FreeBSD. Are you asking about code on the Arduino board or on your FreeBSD PC? I don't see `fork` running on Arduino boards...

Comment: It sounds like you have an Arduino that listens to commands and turns LEDs on and off according to those commands? Is that right? I would add a "blink" command to the Arduino code.  Look for "blink without delay", like here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay  to find out how to stay in the Arduino control 'loop()' and handle incoming commands and blink the LEDs.

Comment: My bad, sorry. Not an Arduino board. I have an UP2 board.
I will have a look on your reference. Thank you.

Comment: So the code works? But you are looking for advice on how best to kick off the program to blink? I'm not sure what you are asking exactly.

Comment: Not really. I was thinking more like: when ./led 3 is selected the process is forked. In this case the LED is blinking and I run another command for the other LED. I can use ./led 5 to turn on RED LED. Now what I want to do next is: IF I run ./led 5 the led.c program should check if the child from (./led 3) is still running and if YES, stop it first, and then start the RED LED. I'm looking for an efficient way to do this. Sorry if I was not very clear earlier.

Comment: to do that you will need some sort of inter-process communication. Unix domain sockets, tcp/ip connections. Searching for a PID of a certain name and killing them might be made to work, but it's not an ideal solution. Many many pitfalls.